# Помогите решить задачку по CSS + Angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

Задачка вроде не сложная, а таску надо решить очень срочно.

```
https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/JvLwNb
```

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.colors = [
        {
            Name: "ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ",
            Value: 1,
            Color: "#47c28d"
        },
        {
            Name: "КРАСНЫЙ",
            Value: 2,
            Color: "red"
        },
        {
            Name: "СИНИЙ",
            Value: 3,
            Color: "blue"
        }
    ];

    $scope.color = 1;

});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
head{
  max-width:100%;
  min-width:0%;
}
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  flex-direction: row;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: 10.5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width:98px;
  height:24px;
}
.text{
  flex-direction: row;
  wigth:100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left:4px;
  color: gray;
}
.form{
  padding:2px 4px;
  height:30px;
}
.form-group{
  flex-direction: row;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  heihth:30px;
}

input{
  width:0px;
  heigth:0px;
}
label{
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
p{
  display:inline-block;
  flex-direction: row;
  wigth:100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left:3px;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top:60px; margin-bottom:20px">Таска по CSS</h1>

        <p>
            Привести набор radio button к виду на картинке, не меняя логику работы (т.е. тип контролла и не добавлять скриптов). Верстку менять можно :) <br />
            <a><img src="https://image.ibb.co/cqqvAd/radio.png" alt="radio" border="0"></a>
        </p>
        <div class="text">Выберите цвет</div>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="c in colors">
                <div class="button" style="border: 1px solid {{c.Color}}; color: {{c.Color}} ">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="$parent.color" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Name}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>color: {{color}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если можно пропишите в комментах что поменялось или что добавилось. СПС!

Comment: Надо привести набор radio button к виду на картинке, не меняя логику работы (т.е. тип контролла и не добавлять скриптов). Верстку менять можно :)

Comment: мысли... просто мысли: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvLqNv

Comment: подредактировал https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/JvLwNb
только немогу понять как текст приподнять (по центру поставить), и всетаки как сделать чтобы сработала копка на active или hover... :(

Comment: код можно в  js добавлять?

Comment: нет. все только на css надо сделать... ((

Comment: уже все настроил, осталось только те кнопки которые неактивным серым закрасить... непойму какой атрибут надо подобрать... https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/JvLwNb

Comment: вроде все заработало, как я вижу.

Answer (score 1):

[Доработал.](https://codepen.io/archivisions/pen/JvLwNb)

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.colors = [
        {
            Name: "ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ",
            Value: 1,
            Color: "#47c28d"
        },
        {
            Name: "КРАСНЫЙ",
            Value: 2,
            Color: "red"
        },
        {
            Name: "СИНИЙ",
            Value: 3,
            Color: "blue"
        }
    ];

    $scope.color = 1;

});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.text{
  flex-direction: row;
  wigth:100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left:5px;
  color: gray;
}

.form{
  padding:2px 5px;
  height:100%;
}

.form-group{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  heihth:25px;
}

input{
  width:0px;
  heigth:0px;
}

.label-form{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;  
  text-align: center;
  width:98px;
  height:24px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

.unchecked {
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3 !important; 
  color: #7d8083 !important;
}
.label-form > input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

p{
  display:inline-block;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left:3px;
  color: gray;
}
.text-color{
  display:border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="margin-top:60px; margin-bottom:20px">Таска по CSS</h1>

        <p>
            Привести набор radio button к виду на картинке, не меняя логику работы (т.е. тип контролла и не добавлять скриптов). Верстку менять можно :) <br />
            <a><img src="https://image.ibb.co/cqqvAd/radio.png" alt="radio"></a>
        </p>
        <div class="text">Выберите цвет</div>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="c in colors">
                    <label  ng-class="{'label-form':true, 'unchecked': c.Value != color}" style="border: 1px solid {{c.Color}}; color: {{c.Color}}"><input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="$parent.color" value="{{c.Value}}">{{c.Name}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="text-color">
        <p>color: {{color}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```